# Animate Text on Mouse Hover via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I need to animate text on mouse hover. But, every time different text appears from my text files OR database. Actually, I want to write the same JavaScript code for my website. 
I already tried to get JavaScript code via Inspect Element. But, It never works.

https://www.marieforleo.com/

I need the same effect on my website
[Click on Logo and See Text Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Dn5s.png)

Comment: You'll need to share the code you're working with for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using basic CSS and JavaScript to set the different texts as required.

```css
div span#initText {
display:inline;
}
div:hover span#initText {
display:none;
}
div span#hoverText {
display:none;
}
div:hover span#hoverText {
display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="textBox">
  <span id="initText">initial text</span>
  <span id="hoverText">hover text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need different texts, you'll need to go JavaScript on this one. Here's an example of what you can do:

```js
const initValue = 'Hover me!';
const hoverValues = [
   'welcome',
   'to',
   'stack',
   'overflow'
];
const elt = document.querySelector('h1');
elt.onmouseover = () => elt.innerHTML = hoverValues[Math.floor(hoverValues.length*Math.random())];
elt.onmouseout = () => elt.innerHTML = initValue;
```

```html
<h1>Hover me!</h1>
```